# Como buscar o menor preço em uma entidade com Spring Data JPA em um JPARepository? (keywords ou JPQL)

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-jpa

Tenho a seguinte entidade em java utilizando spring:

```
public class ItemVendedor implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ItemVendedorPK id = new ItemVendedorPK();
    private BigDecimal preco;
    private Boolean disponivel;
    private Date dt_insert;
    private Date dt_update;

    @EmbeddedId
    public ItemVendedorPK getId() {
        return id;
    }
...GETs AND SETs
```

Esta entidade é ligada a uma classe JPARepository conforme abaixo:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemVendedorRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemVendedor,  ItemVendedorPK >, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ItemVendedor> {

}
```

o que eu quero criar é uma consulta que me retorne um objeto do tipo ItemVendedor, porém deve buscar o objeto de menor preço.

O uso de keywords no repository me permite utilizar alguma função similar ao MIN() do SQL ou JPQL? Como poderia fazer isso utilizando a estratégia de keyWords?

Tentei utilizar @Query em JPQL no respository, como abaixo:

```
@Query("SELECT min(iv.preco) FROM ItemVendedor iv where (iv.id.produto.id = :produtoId) ")
Optional<ItemVendedor> findCestaFavorita( @Param(value = "produtoId") Long produto);
```

Porém nesta abordagem sempre me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
"message": "java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to com.eclodir.voucomprei.model.entity.ItemVendedor",
```

Como buscar o produto de menor preço?

Comment: Acredito que o erro do `@Query` é que você está criando uma função do tipo `Optional<ItemVendedor>` mas no SQL retorna `min(iv.preco)` que é do tipo `BigDecimal`

Comment: Pode ser realmente, estou forçando ele puxar um único campo, mas eu queria o objeto completo, vou fazer um teste colocando os demais campos para ver o comportamento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não conheço muito o JPA e o ecossistema Spring em geral, mas o erro do cast é porque definiu uma função do tipo `Optional<ItemVendedor>` mas no SQL retorna `min(iv.preco)` que é do tipo `BigDecimal`

Então o correto se você quer pegar o menor valor é:

```
@Query("SELECT min(iv.preco) FROM ItemVendedor iv where (iv.id.produto.id = :produtoId)")
BigDecimal findCestaFavorita(@Param(value = "produtoId") Long produto);
```

Mas se você quer a linha que contenha o menor valor então, seu SQL está incorreto,  você deve selecionar as colunas que deseja (ou `*` para todas) e ordenar de forma descendente, como você quer apenas **o menor** (singular), também coloque um limite de 1:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ItemVendedor iv where (iv.id.produto.id = :produtoId) ORDER BY iv.preco DESC LIMIT 1")
Optional<ItemVendedor> findCestaFavorita(@Param(value = "produtoId") Long produto);
```

Comment: Legal Guilherme, consegui fazer aqui. Obrigado pelo apoio.